# Select LinkedServer inside a function

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to `SELECT` a function using `LinkedServer` inside a stored procedure but I'm getting an error

> ERROR: Remote table-valued function calls are not allowed.

So what I did is to create this code:

```
DECLARE @YearOF INT = 2019
DECLARE @MonthOF INT = 12

EXEC VM_DB_FMIS.fmis.dbo.sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM 
fn_some_function(@YearOF_Q,@MonthOF_Q)'
,N'@YearOF_Q INT, @MonthOF_Q INT',@YearOF,@MonthOF
```

But If I do this then I need to update all existing stored procedure that using the said function. So I tried to create my own function with the same name that would produce the same result.

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fn_some_function] (
@YearOF INT,
@MonthOF INT
)
RETURNS @DataTable TABLE
(
    obrno VARCHAR(50), 
    YearOF INT
)
BEGIN

DECLARE @t1 TABLE(obrno VARCHAR(50), YearOF INT)

INSERT INTO @t1
EXEC VM_DB_FMIS.fmis.dbo.sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM 
fn_some_function(@YearOF_Q,@MonthOF_Q)'
,N'@YearOF_Q INT, @MonthOF_Q INT',@YearOF,@MonthOF

INSERT INTO @DataTable
SELECT * FROM @t1
RETURN
END
```

But now I'm getting this error

> Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC' within a function.

So is there any other workaround to do this?

Comment: use a `Stored Procedure` instead

Comment: @Squirrel If I do that then I get an error "An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested."

Comment: @FrostyPinky That would be due to the stored proc you are calling also having an `insert` statement in it. I believe in regards to insert statements in stored procs, the most you can go is 2 deep